# Probability on the same wavefront

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

My question is as follows. Is the probability of finding the particle on the same wavefront of its de Broglie wave the same?

Comment: Are you asking whether there is an equal probability of finding it anywhere along a "wavefront"?

Comment: Yes that's what I am asking,  Jaywalker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. It is perfectly possible to produce particle wavepackets that have a varying particle probability density $|\Psi(\vec r)|^2$ along their wavefronts. The simplest example is probably a gaussian wavepacket moving along the $z$ axis,
$$
\Psi(\vec r) = N \exp\left(- \frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}+ i kz\right),
$$
for which the wavefronts are the planes $z=\rm const$, along which the particle probability density
$$
|\Psi(x,y,z)|^2 = N_z^2 \exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sigma^2}\right)
$$
depends on $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

A particles propagation and behavior is dictated by its wave equation ($\Psi(\vec r, t)$ in its most basic form) in Quantum Mechanics. The probability of finding the particle in a small volume is then given by

$P(small volume)=\vert\Psi(\vec r, t)\vert^2d\vec r^3$

This means that the probability is directly related to the amplitude of the wave function at any given point and time. Provided your wavefront has a uniform amplitude this means the particle has a uniform probability of being observed anywhere along it.

Comment: don't you mean $d\vec{r}^3$?

Comment: "Provided your wavefront has a uniform amplitude" is an overly restrictive assumption. Plenty of physically-reasonable wavepackets (like, say a gaussian wavepacket, $\psi(\vec r) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}r^2 + i \vec k\cdot\vec r)$) have non-uniform amplitudes along their wavefronts.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I absolutely agree and its in the rarest cases that the waveform is uniform (if ever in real life). But the argument still stands that the probability of finding the particle is related to wavefunction as described above.